# In linux bash scripting, what does >> do in pushd command?

Tags: linux, bash, pushd

I'm new to learning bash scripting and I'm confused about the following code:

```
build_web_apps()
{
    for app in $web_apps
    do
        log "Building $app web app..."
        pushed $GIPHY_HOME/../$app >> /dev/null
        ...
        ... (some code)
        ...
        popd >> /dev/null
    done
}
```

I know what `pushd` and `popd` is, but what is the effect of `>>` in these lines?

Comment: It is very close to the linked duplicate. Answering it wouldn't add anything useful than the existing answers in that post.

Comment: `pushd` and `popd` print the current stack values to stdout, every time they are invoked. One can suppress these messages by re-directing them to `/dev/null` which just consumes it without putting it on screen. Though `>` is all you need, doing `>>` to `/dev/null` doesn't make much of a difference